# Why is correlation obtained from nlme different from Pearson correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

```
Fixed effects: Ratio ~ ADF + CP + FCM + DMI + DIM 
                 Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  3.1199808 0.16237303 158 19.214896  0.0000
ADF         -0.0265626 0.00406990 158 -6.526603  0.0000
CP          -0.0534021 0.00539108 158 -9.905636  0.0000
FCM         -0.0149314 0.00353524 158 -4.223598  0.0000
DMI          0.0072318 0.00498779 158  1.449894  0.1491
DIM         -0.0008994 0.00019408 158 -4.634076  0.0000

Correlation: 
    (Intr) ADF    CP     FCM    DMI   
ADF -0.628                            
CP  -0.515  0.089                     
FCM -0.299  0.269 -0.203              
DMI -0.229 -0.145  0.083 -0.624       
DIM -0.113  0.127 -0.061  0.010 -0.047
```

I obtained these value from `lme` function for mixed model. However, I am wondering why the values for correlation of fixed effect provided here differ from what I obtain using `cor.test` function (Pearson correlation)

Comment: These are correlations between the coefficients in the model; that is, the slopes associated with these variables. `cor.test` gives you correlations between the variables themselves.

Comment: Hi Aaron, could you please tell me what can we learn from this rather than pearson correlation. I understand the problem with estimations if for example ADF and CP are strongly correlated. I used pearson correlation, but could I use the the results above to evaluate the same thing?

Comment: That would probably take more of a mini-lecture about what's going on, which I don't have the time to provide, though more than likely someone else at CrossValidated will, once this question is migrated.  (No need for you to do anything; this will happen automatically.)

Comment: Try to get a copy of Pinheiro, J. & Bates, D.M., 2000. Mixed-effects models in S and S-PLUS,Springer. It's explained in there.

Comment: Or any regression text, for that matter; it's not specific to mixed models.